# Joomla Filter Menu

Tags: php, joomla

I need to display a menu in Joomla and remove 2 items from it. I am very new to Joomla can someone please help me ?

Its like displaying all menu items in list except for 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you going through the **[joomla quick start guide](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=joomla+quick+start+guide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)**, it also tells you how to add/remove menu items other than other great stuff very important for the new comers, it really helped me getting started with joomla. Note it is in pdf format.